# SD, ext4 and journaling

Tags: mount, ext4, sd-card

I want to use a SD card formatted with ext4 and mount it as /home/user/data 
I ask if is better disabling journaling to preserve SD. If so, can I have my internal hard disk (/dev/sda) with journaling and SD without it? Is there any issues in doing this? Is this a good way: http://www.techpository.com/linux-how-to-disableenable-journaling-on-an-ext4-filesystem/ ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, disabling journaling should reduce the amount of writes to the memory device.

The command `mke2fs -t ext4 -O ^has_journal /dev/mmcblk0pX` will format with journaling disabled.

See https://superuser.com/questions/799233/why-i-cannot-format-a-microsd-to-ext4?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I chose to format SD with ext2

Answer (score 2):

If you still care, try F2FS instead of extX. It is developed for SD cards only.

It have a lot of pros for them, like:

- Copy on write (CoW), to reduce R/W
- Roll-backs, dual checkpoints (may be very useful)

and some others, including no traditional journaling.

To create it, you need `f2fs-tools` (`mkfs.f2fs`) or GParted. Support (mounting and working) is included in linux kernel, including some android builds.

Comment: Can you please expand this comment into a full answer? What are the benefits, and how is F2FS used?